# Why does my while loop calculate incorrect value of the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, data-structures, while-loop

I am trying to find greatest length of a word from the string return it by using values of each letter from alphabets by assigning each letter it's value as per it's rank . So for example **For a string s = 'abcd a', I intend to return 10 [a=1 + b=2 + c =3 + d=4] .But, I am getting output as 7** When I debugged the code, I noticed that in while loop my code skips i=2 and directly jumps on i=3. Where am I going wrong? Below is my code.

```
class Solution(object):

    def highest_scoring_word(self,s):

        # Dictionary of English letters
      dt = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,
            'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,
            'm':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,
            'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,
            'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
      value_sum =0
      max_value =value_sum
      for i in range(0,len(s)):
          if s.upper():
              s= s.lower()
              words = s.split()

              # convert the string in char array
              to_char_array = list(words[i])
              j=0
              while j<len(to_char_array):
                  if to_char_array[j] in dt.keys() :
                        value_sum = max(dt.get(to_char_array[j]),value_sum + dt.get(to_char_array[j]))
                        max_value = max(value_sum,max_value)
                  else:
                      pass
                  j +=j+1
              return max_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = 'abcd a'
    print(Solution().highest_scoring_word(p))
```

`

I have created a dictionary where I have stored all letters in english alphabet and their values and later I have split the string into words using split() and then after converting each individual word into character array I have traversed it to find their occurrence in the dictionary and add to the final value. I am expecting to get a correct value of a string and finally the greatest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
class Solution(object):

    def highest_scoring_word(self,s):

        # Dictionary of English letters
      dt = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,
            'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,
            'm':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,
            'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,
            'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
      value_sum1 =0
      max_value1 =value_sum1
      value_sum2 =0
      max_value2 =value_sum2
      for i in range(0,len(s)):
          if s.upper():
              s= s.lower()
              words = s.split()
              if len(words)>1:
                  # convert the string in char array
                  to_char_array = list(words[0])

                  j=0
                  while j<len(to_char_array):
                      if to_char_array[j] in dt.keys() :
                            value_sum1 = max(dt.get(to_char_array[j]),value_sum1 + dt.get(to_char_array[j]))
                            max_value1 = max(value_sum1,max_value1)
                      else:
                          pass
                      j=j+1
            
                  to_char_array = list(words[1])

                  j=0
                  while j<len(to_char_array):
                      if to_char_array[j] in dt.keys() :
                            value_sum2 = max(dt.get(to_char_array[j]),value_sum2 + dt.get(to_char_array[j]))
                            max_value2 = max(value_sum2,max_value2)
                      else:
                          pass
                      j=j+1
                  if max_value2>max_value1:
                          return max_value2
                  elif max_value1>max_value2:
                          return max_value1
                  else:
                          return 'Both words have equal score'
              else:
                      # convert the string in char array
                      to_char_array = list(words[i])
                      j=0
                      while j<len(to_char_array):
                          if to_char_array[j] in dt.keys() :
                                value_sum1 = max(dt.get(to_char_array[j]),value_sum1 + dt.get(to_char_array[j]))
                                max_value1 = max(value_sum1,max_value1)
                          else:
                              pass
                          j=j+1
                      return max_value1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = 'abcd fg'
    print(Solution().highest_scoring_word(p))
```

Comment: And in line 14 you are probably thinking of using `if s.isupper():` But if you do that you have to give an else statement to catch the times when the string s is not in capital letters

Comment: But here if I use the input 'abcd fg' I should get 13 as output since [f=6,g=7] but I am still getting 10

Comment: If you remove the space in between the input 'abcd fg' and change it to 'abcdfg' it works. Since you are trying to find the highest scoring word adding a space in between makes it two words, this creates the problem. Leave a comment if you want to find the highest scoring word when it has a space between it and I'll try to find a solution for that :)

Comment: Yes, I do want to find highest score when it has a space and I want to schieve it through the code that I have written.

Comment: 'abcd fg' should give 23 not 13

Comment: No, I want greater value, the value of 'fg' is ( 6+7) =13 than abcd (1+2+3+4)=10

Comment: Hey I edited my answer. Is this the way you want it?

Comment: It's giving me  " to_char_array = list(words[1])
IndexError: list index out of range" when I give input as 'taxi' or 'abcd'

Comment: Try again, I've edited the answer. The problem was that I thought you wanted to compare two words always. Now the code works if you input one or two words.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a class and methods, make use of them:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as dt


class Solution(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.scores = {}
        self.words = data.lower().strip().split()

    def get_scoring(self):
        # for each word caculate the scoring
        for word in self.words:
            score = 0
            # for each character in the word, find its index in 'a..z' and add it to score
            # same as in your dt implementation (just using index not absolute values)
            for c in word:
                score += dt.find(c) + 1
            self.scores[word] = score
        print(self.scores)
        # filer the dictionary by its greates value in order to get the word with max score:
        return max(self.scores.keys(), key=lambda k: self.scores[k])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = 'abcd fg11'
    maxWord = Solution(p).get_scoring()
    print(maxWord)
```

Out:

```
{'abcd': 10, 'fg11': 13}
fg11
```

Comment: I am not really good at using lambdas , could you explain me where I am going wrong in my code?

Comment: @Niklaus: Edited and changed the list comprehension to a regular loop :)

Comment: I will go through it , thank you. Could you suggest me some blog to be better at lambdas? I literally don't find them comfortable. Thank you

Comment: [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind could you tell where i am going wrong in my original code? I made changes as per the suggestion given by @Retro_Zapper and when I used this input **'abcd fg'** it gives me 10 instead of 13. I debugged it and found that my while loop doesn't check 'fg' word.

Comment: I did not check in detail, but `return max_value` looks suspicious, as `return` breaks the `for loop `.

Comment: Could you check it please? I have been stuck on it since morning. There is some issue with my while loop, it just doesn't traverse 'fg'

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe of interest that the code can be greatly simplified by using features available in Python:

```
the_sum = sum(ord(c)-96 for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha())
```

to  break this down. `for c in s.lower()` gets the lower-case characters one by one; the function `ord()` gives the numerical value with `a` of 97 so we subtract to get 1. Then we check if the character is a letter and if so accept it. Then `sum()` adds up all the numbers. You could break up this one line an check how the separate parts work.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will check this line of code. Also , out of curiosity I would really like to know where am I going wrong in my original code because I have spent almost a day on it and still I am not able to remove the bug.

Comment: I would like to suggest a way to sort out such problems. Copy your code into `https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit` and visualize your code stepping through and the variables changing.